# Return matching objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to search matching value objects from a given array depending on searchString. e.g., the search string would be 'Object 0'.

```
var objArray = [
   { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321', secondVal:'stack' },
   { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: 'Object 0', secondVal: 'Overflow' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850', secondVal: 'Context' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046', secondVal: 'Object 1' },
   { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '78', secondVal: 'test' }
];
```

Now I want to search in the array with `Object` as a value. Means it should return me 0, 1 & 3 object

Help will be appreciated

Comment: [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) - in other words `objArray.filter(item => Object.values(item).includes('Object 0'));`

Comment: working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csaana?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts using `array.filter`

Comment: @Pradeep Jain, what if i want to search only for 'Object'? it is returning me empty array

Comment: @PrasannaSasne you can use simple loop. Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each object in the array, get the keys for each object to prevent yourself from dynamic properties in the object, and then check if the value for that key has `Object` as a substring or not. Note that `obj[key].toString()` in the below code. `toString()` is used because your `id` has integer value and `indexOf()` works on string value. Thus, using that will prevent from error.

```js
var objArray = [
   { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321', secondVal:'stack' },
   { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: 'Object 0', secondVal: 'Overflow' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850', secondVal: 'Context' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046', secondVal: 'Object 1' },
   { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '78', secondVal: 'test' }
];

var res = [];
objArray.filter((obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
    if(obj[key].toString().indexOf('Object') !== -1){
      res.push(obj);
    }
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with the `array.filter` method and a loop over all properties within this filter method.

```
var objArray = [
   { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321', secondVal:'stack' },
   { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: 'Object 0', secondVal: 'Overflow' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850', secondVal: 'Context' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046', secondVal: 'Object 0' },
   { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '78', secondVal: 'test' }
];

var filteredArray = objArray.filter((obj) => {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === 'Object 0') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I dont want to search for exact match. search string may be in lowercase also. i tried using '==' but it's not working. it is returning as empty array

Comment: `==` doesn't ignore case. You have to convert your strings into lowercase for comparison. Just replace the if-statement with this: `if (obj[key].toLowerCase() === 'object 0')`. For other comparisons you may have to use regex.

Comment: If you'd like to use regex you could replace the if statement by the javscript [match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function: `if (obj[key].match(/object/i)) { ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in Arrays.

Here's a sample of what you're looking for

```
var objArray = [
   { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321', secondVal:'stack' },
   { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: 'Object 0', secondVal: 'Overflow' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850', secondVal: 'Context' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046', secondVal: 'Object 0' },
   { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '78', secondVal: 'test' }
];

var resultArray = objArray.filter(function (d) { 
    return Object.values(d).indexOf('Object 0') != -1 
});
```

The value of `d` in the `filter()` method takes each object from your array of object. `Object.values()` returns an array of the values associated with each of the `keys` in the object. The `indexOf()` essentially checks if the string you want to match is available in the array. In case it matches, the result is put in `resultArray` else it's ignored. The final `resultArray` looks as follows:

```
[
    {id: 0, name: "Object 0", otherProp: "321", secondVal: "stack"},
    {id: 1, name: "O1", otherProp: "Object 0", secondVal: "Overflow"},
    {id: 3, name: "Almost There", otherProp: "046", secondVal: "Object 0"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.filter()` and  `array.includes()`, `Object.values()` to do this.

```
var objArray = [
      {id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321', secondVal: 'stack'},
      {id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: 'Object 0', secondVal: 'Overflow'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850', secondVal: 'Context'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046', secondVal: 'Object 0'},
      {id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '78', secondVal: 'test'},
    ];


const result = objArray.filter((object) => {
  const values = Object.values(object);
  return values.includes('Object 0');
});

console.log(result);
```